# Выводит один массив вместо двух

Tags: php, sql, массивы, pdo

Через pdo вывожу записи из бд mysql проблема такая из бд должно выйти 2 записи а значит 2 массива но у меня 1 массив вот код

```html
$year = $_POST["year"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
#подключение к бд
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT news_id, title, FROM_UNIXTIME(date) AS readableDate 
FROM re_news 
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = :year AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = :month");
   $stmt->bindParam(':year', $year);
   $stmt->bindParam(':month', $month);
   $stmt->execute();
   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   print_r($row);
```

выводит такое

```html
Array
(
    [news_id] => 7
    [title] => мс смваааап
    [readableDate] => 2017-12-28 22:48:51
)
```

а в бд как нужно всё [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[fetch](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php)** - выводит **одну** строку.

нужно пользоваться циклом `while` например

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

либо использовать **[fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

---

Иногда в доки полезно заглядывать ;-)

Comment: спасибо вам блин снова 3 символа не доглядел fetchAll сделал всё норм